Multiple regression with covariates output in SPSS interpretation of tables
I have run a multiple regression in SPSS looking at the association between 1 IV and 1 DV with 3 covariates (age, sex, education). I am unable to understand the how to interpret these tables: 1. Variables entered/removed table, Model summary table, ANOVA table, coefficients table, excluded variables and residual statistics table.
Could someone please take some time to explain the way I need to interpret these tables. I am a complete novice to this.
Thanks!
I have understood the correlations table but not the others.
